How to Dynamically (programatically at runtime) insert new AntMatchPattern to Spring Security
I need to dynamically create/remove roles and AntMatcherPattern for these roles.
Imagine that the ADMIN of the application wants to create a new role like "Accountant junior" and give to this role these access:
GET - "/accounts"
POST - "/accounts"
The ADMIN do that and then see that the "Accountant Junior" cannot create new accounts, so the ADMIN need to be able to remove the:
POST - "/accounts".

I currently have the Authority.java:
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Authority implements GrantedAuthority {

    @Id
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;
    private String pattern;
    private String role;


    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return this.role;
    }
}

This is my SecurityFilterChain configuration:
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthConfig {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1)
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, AccessRuleAuthorizationManager access) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::sameOrigin))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> {
                    requests.requestMatchers("/auth/authenticate").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().access(access);
                })
                .sessionManagement( session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

}

As you can see, I have the AccessRuleAuthorizationManager.java class:
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AccessRuleAuthorizationManager implements AuthorizationManager<RequestAuthorizationContext> {

    private final AuthorityRepository rules;
    private RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager delegate;

    @Override
    public AuthorizationDecision check(Supplier<Authentication> authentication, RequestAuthorizationContext object) {
        return this.delegate.check(authentication, object.getRequest());
    }

    @EventListener
    void applyRules(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.Builder builder = builder();
        for (Authority rule : this.rules.findAll()) {
            builder.add(
                    new AntPathRequestMatcher(rule.getPattern()),
                    AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasAuthority(rule.getRole())
            );
        }
        this.delegate = builder.build();
    }
}

The problem here is that these rules are applied only on Application Ready Event.
I could create an Http endpoint that call this method, or even add an @PostPersist listener on Authority.java... but doesn't seems right.
Is there a native solution? Or do you have an elegant solution for that?

dont remove the endpoint, give them a POST role, and a GET role instead.
